# Get-request sends null in web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have an action for a GET-reqeust:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Answer([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    game.LogUserAnswer(cookie["user"].Value, value);
    return String.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>: {1} <br>", cookie["user"].Value, game.UserGuess(value));
}
```

When I'm trying to pass any data I've always got null. I invoke the action with ajax-call:

```
$('#btnAnswer').click(function () {
    var value = $('#Answer').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: uri + '/' + 'Answer' + '/' + value,
        data: { '': value },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#resultsBox').append('<strong>' + data + '</strong><br>');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

In the Fiddler the url is next: `GET /api/values/Answer/132312?=132312 HTTP/1.1`
I tried to send another request: `GET /api/values/Answer/132312 HTTP/1.1` 
but still in my action value is null.

Also I've changed public string Answer(string value) (without FromBody), in this case application can't find needful `HTTP`.

Could you please tell, what I'm missing?

*Update 1 *
 var uri = 'api/values';

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "apianswer",
    routeTemplate: "Home/api/values/answer/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Answer", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 ? What if you open the browser dev tools -> network tab and copy the URL and try that directly on a browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get requests does not have body**! You should send your parameter as part of your route

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Home/api/values/answer/{value}"]
public string Answer(string value = null //in case you want to call answer without any value provided)
{...}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: uri + '/' + 'Answer' + '/' + value,
    ...
});
```

or as a query string

```
[HttpGet]
public string Answer(string value)
{...}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: uri + '/' + 'Answer',
    data: {value: value}
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I tried your case and still got the error: 'No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '.
Also I've just added my route for this action if it's important.